# Discord.py kick command not working (missing perms error)

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a kick command that does a double check with the user before carrying out action for my discord bot, and came up with this:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def kick(ctx,
               member: discord.Member = None,
               *,
               reason="No reason provided"):

    server_name = ctx.guild.name
    user = member

    if member == None:
        await ctx.send(
            f'{x_mark} **{ctx.message.author.name},** please mention somebody to kick.')
        return

    if member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.send(
            f'{x_mark} **{ctx.message.author.name},** you can\'t kick yourself, silly.')
        return

    embedcheck = discord.Embed(
        title="Kick",
        colour=0xFFD166,
        description=f'Are you sure you want to kick **{user}?**')

    embeddone = discord.Embed(
        title="Kicked",
        colour=0x06D6A0,
        description=f'**{user}** has been kicked from the server.')

    embedfail = discord.Embed(
        title="Not Kicked",
        colour=0xEF476F,
        description=f'The kick did not carry out.')

    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embedcheck)
    await msg.add_reaction(check_mark)
    await msg.add_reaction(x_mark)

    def check(rctn, user):
        return user.id == ctx.author.id and str(rctn) in [check_mark, x_mark]

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for(
                'reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
            if str(reaction.emoji) == check_mark:
                await msg.edit(embed=embeddone)
                await user.kick(reason=reason)
                if reason == None:
                    await user.send(
                        f'**{user.name}**, you were kicked from {server_name}. No reason was provided.'
                    )
                else:
                    await user.send(
                        f'**{user.name}**, you were kicked from {server_name} for {reason}.'
                    )

                return

            elif str(reaction.emoji) == x_mark:
                await msg.edit(embed=embedfail)
                return

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await msg.edit(embed=embedfail)
            return
```

However when I do this, I get the error:

```
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I have no clue why this is happening, as the bot has every permission checked, as do I, and I am the server owner. Any help would be appriciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I found the error, when running the command it would try to kick the user of the command instead of the specified member. Here is my updated code:

```py
  @commands.command()
  @commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
  @commands.bot_has_permissions(kick_members = True)
  async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):

    server_name = ctx.guild.name

    if member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.send(
            f'{x_mark} **{ctx.message.author.name},** you can\'t kick yourself, silly.')
        return

    embedcheck = discord.Embed(
        title="Kick",
        colour=0xFFD166,
        description=f'Are you sure you want to kick **{member}?**')

    embeddone = discord.Embed(
        title="Kicked",
        colour=0x06D6A0,
        description=f'**{member}** has been kicked from the server.')

    embedfail = discord.Embed(
        title="Not Kicked",
        colour=0xEF476F,
        description=f'The kick did not carry out.')

    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embedcheck)
    await msg.add_reaction(check_mark)
    await msg.add_reaction(x_mark)

    def check(rctn, user):
        return user.id == ctx.author.id and str(rctn) in [check_mark, x_mark]

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for(
                'reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
            if str(reaction.emoji) == check_mark:
                await msg.edit(embed=embeddone)
                await member.kick(reason=reason)
                await member.send(f'**{member.name}**, you were kicked from {server_name} for {reason}.')
                return

            elif str(reaction.emoji) == x_mark:
                await msg.edit(embed=embedfail)
                return

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await msg.edit(embed=embedfail)
            return

  @kick.error
  async def kick_error(self, ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f'{x_mark} **{ctx.message.author.name}**, you need to mention someone to kick.')
      elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send(f'{x_mark} **{ctx.message.author.name}**, I could not find a user with that name.')
      else:
        raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you are checking for `manage_guild` which is not the correct permission. Also keep in mind you are mixing up `bot` and `commands`

```py
@bot.command()
@bot.has_permissions(kick_user = True) # to check the user itself
@bot.bot_has_permissions(kick_user = True) # to check the bot
async def kick(ctx):
```

Remember to allow all intents like this

```py
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)
```

Comment: Upon doing that I get the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 214, in <module>
    @bot.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'has_permissions'`

Comment: You should use whatever you named your bot in here `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)`

Comment: Hmm, I tried doing
`intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)` 
but I get the error
 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'`

Comment: Check the code above i added it. Make sure you update your library.